# Is there a way to get key name from keyCode/which for certain language programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, localization, single-page-application

So, here's the case:

- I have a search field on an html page (app), which gives suggestions as a user types
- A user can type stuff there in either language X or English
- (s)he can forget what language layout (s)he currently has and start typing in a wrong layout

What I'd like to achieve:

- on input, make the same change as in the field in a couple of variables, in one in English, in another – in the language X
- make suggestions based on the two variables, not the field content, so that if the user has confused language layout, (s)he will get an adequate suggestion anyway

Now, the question is: is it possible to convert `e.which` or `e.keyCode` programmaticaly into a standart layout letter for certain language without listing stuff like

```
var keysMap = {
  ..,
  keyCode: { englishLetter: .., languageXletter: .. } ,
  ..
}
```

(in other words, do browsers know about what letter should a `keyCode`/`which` correspond to? or does so jQuery?)

I imply two cases:

1. language X is known (say, I can hardcode it)
2. language X is unknown, can it be extracted from the browser to reduce this to the case 1?

PS in a certain sense, I'd like implement an analogue of PuntoSwitcher/KeyboardNinja/.. on the side of the page (but only in sense of the suggesion generation, I guess that it's impossible to force keyboard layout switch from a web page).

PS2 Ok, for clarification let me copy my comment for T30 here:

Let language X be Russian like it is for me. Consider this: I'd like to type "request", but my keyboard layout is Russian, not English, so I get "куйгуые". Or I'd like to type Russian "запрос", but I have English layout and so I get "pfghjc". This is what I mean by "wrong layout". I'd like to interpret "pfghjc" as both "pfghjc" and "запрос" or "куйгуые" as both "куйгуые" and "request", and give suggestions based on both versions. This way I'll help the user even if (s)he hasn't switched to the "correct" language.

Comment: What do you mean with 'wrong layout'? Can't understand why you have many layout.

Comment: @T30 Well, let language X be Russian like it is for me. Consider this: I'd like to type "request", but my keyboard layout is Russian, not English, so I get "куйгуые". Or I'd like to type Russian "запрос", but I have English layout and so I get "pfghjc". This is what I mean by "wrong layout". I'd like to interpret "pfghjc" as both "pfghjc" and "запрос" or "куйгуые" as both "куйгуые" and "request", and give suggestions based on both versions. This way I'll help the user even if (s)he hasn't switched to the "correct" language.

Comment: Nice question! (Consider to edit the queston adding this comment, it could help users to better understand the point)

Comment: sounds like you just need to make use of a translation api

Comment: @charlietfl, do you mean Google Translate API (https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs) or something else? The point is, I'm looking for a way to achieve this offline, too.